# How to fix color buffer error in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

This is the Error we get from our Event Log:

```
07:43   Emulator: Trying to erase a non-existent color buffer with handle 0
07:43   Emulator: Trying to erase a non-existent color buffer with handle 0
07:43   Emulator: Trying to erase a non-existent color buffer with handle 0
07:43   Emulator: Trying to erase a non-existent color buffer with handle 0
07:43   Emulator: Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
07:43   Emulator: Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
07:43   Emulator: Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...
07:43   Emulator: Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...
07:43   Emulator: Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
07:43   Emulator: Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
07:43   Emulator: Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/csdesigndevelopment/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
07:43   Emulator: Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/csdesigndevelopment/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
07:43   Emulator: Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/Users/csdesigndevelopment/.QtWebEngineProcess'
07:43   Emulator: Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/Users/csdesigndevelopment/.QtWebEngineProcess'
07:43   Emulator: Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory... 
07:43   Emulator: Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
07:43   Emulator: Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory..
07:43   Emulator: Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...
07:43   Emulator: [1204/074353.477524:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale
07:43   Emulator: [1204/074353.477612:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale
```

Any help would be great:

thanks!!!!!!!!